# Constructor default-public and private variables

Tags: c++

I know java and i learning now c++.I learn it more easier than other language it has many same things.My question is in class in a book there is a full constructor but i didn't face the default constructor anywhere.Has c++ default constructor,if yes should i write it?Additional to,i want to test and something,on this class there is in `public:` and down of it there are variables and after some time there is `private:` and down of it there are some variables too.Is like java public and privates variables? but instead of write `private int numbers;` on c++ we write

```
private:
int numbers;
int coffee;
```

Am i right?

Comment: What do you expect the "default constructor" to do for you?

Comment: "it has many same things"  dont get mislead by C++ and Java having similar looking syntax, the two languages almost could not be more different than they are... well its a bit exaggerated, but I think the message is clear ;)

Comment: if i understand good you mean that they are similar? :)

Comment: @tadman i learn in java always when i write a class i should always write the default constructor.If i didnt my teacher will tell me or cut me marks.When i see some exercises on c++ i didnt see.Now , you could tell me ask my teacher why on c++  but he is vacation because we have summer and i wanted to start reading c++ because i like learning :)

Comment: no just the opposite. Knowing Java saves you from reading maybe half a page in a C++ book. The rest you need to learn from scratch. Dont try to apply what you know in Java to C++, this might go ok for a very short while, but in C++ you can easily shoot yourself in your own foot (afaik this isnt possible in Java, qed)

Comment: Search the internet for "c++ rule of 3".

Comment: @tobi303 yes i see there are a lot of things similars but not all of them.I am bad asking here on comments but a method void on java doesnt return anything.Here on c++ is same?I read the book nowhere refer it that,but it hasnt the void and after the return statement.So if i am not tired you could you answer me this only question?now i remember it.I facing all time "problems" ,is this right or is different?I hope you catch me

Comment: yes the keywords are `private`,`protected` and `public` and a `void` return type means that a function returns nothing and thats actually almost all similarities between C++ and Java I know of :P

Comment: @tobi303 thanks  a lot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that your teacher was marking points off for not including a Default Constructor is... interesting, to say the least.

As a general principle, both in Java and C++, a *Constructor* is responsible for initializing the object to a fully formed state. The reason to have a Default Constructor is to enable a fully formed object to be constructed without any explicit input. But that can get weird:

```
//Java
public class Student {
    public String name;
    public int age;
    public Student() {
        this("", 0);
    }
    public Student(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
}

//C++
class Student {
public: //Everything after this point has 'public' access modifier; is like putting 
//'public' in front of each variable and method
    std::string name;
    int age;
    Student() : Student("", 0) {}
    Student(std::string name, int age) : name(std::move(name)), age(age) {}
};
```

In this example, `Student` has a Constructor which initializes the object with provided values, and a Default Constructor which initializes the object to have an empty name and an age of 0.

But think about that: *does that make sense?* Does it make sense for a valid `Student` object to have no name, or for it to be possible to construct a `Student` object if you don't know their name? Forgetting the functional requirements for a moment (i.e., arrays can be difficult to construct if the object doesn't have a Default Constructor), it can be logically inconsistent to have an object that can be Constructed without input like that. Depending on your use-case, it might make more sense to *not* have a Default Constructor.

So determining whether to include a Default-Constructor in your code is a matter of design principles, and has nothing to do with whether you're using Java or C++, or most programming languages for that matter.

Regarding your other concerns:

`public:`, `protected:`, and `private:` have different rules than in Java (`public` and `private` are mostly the same, `protected` is the odd-one out, and Java's `default` doesn't exist in C++, but can be emulated through the use of the `friend` keyword), but their behavior is easy to identify:

```
class example {
//private:
//'class' declarations have everything 'private' by default, 'struct' makes things 'public' by default
    int val; //is private
    std::string type; //is private
public: //Will be public until another access modifier is used
    example() {} //is public
    example(int val, std::string type) : val(val), type(std::move(type)) {} //is public
    void do_something() { //is public
        private_function();
    }
private: //Will be private until another access modifier is used
    void private_function() { //is private
        val++;
    }
};
```

In Java, you'd write the same code like this:

```
public class example {
    private int val;
    private String type;

    public example() {}
    public example(int val, String type) {
        this.val = val;
        this.type = type;
    }
    public void do_something() {
        private_function();
    }
    private void private_function() {
        val++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell exactly what you are asking.  But:
1) A default constructor is generated for you if you don't create any constructors yourself.  It's public by default.
2) The generated default constructor will default construct the base classes and members of the class in declaration order (virtual bases (if any), depth first, right to left in order of declaration, then normal bases in left to right order of declaration, then member variables in order of declaration.  If any of these cannot be default constructed, then the default constructor cannot be generated for you.
3) If there are const members or reference members, or members that do not have default constructors, or your class has bases that do not have default constructors, the default constructor cannot be generated since those members must be initialized with one or more values.
4) If you define a constructor, and you also want the compiler to generate a default constructor for you, and a default constructor is valid in your code, do this:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass() = default; // explicitly tell compiler to generate a default
    MyClass(int x) { ...} // normally would suppress gen of default ctor
};
```

If I understand your question about access specifiers, they are like labels, and everything that follows them has that access specification until you write another one that changes it.  In a class, by default access is private.  In a struct, access is public.

Hope this helps.

Comment: before i accepted ,i dont know if you know java.On here,c++ there is private:
int numbers;
int coffee; but in java there is private int numbers; is the same?